# Scale UIView using UISlider

Tags: ios, uislider, cgaffinetransformscale

I'm trying to scale an UIView using a UISlider but the result is not good with this approach:

```
- (void)setScale:(float)scale {
   CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale(myView.transform, scale, scale);
            myView.transform = transform;

}
```

thanks

Comment: What does "not good" mean? Does it not work? Does it work but not like you want it to? Is it a performance problem?

Comment: Works bad with strange behavior.

Comment: the void instead of IBAction is because this method is called from a delegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the scale based on the identity transform (which represents the object without any changes). This code works:

```
- (void)sliderDidChangeValue:(id)sender
{
    // the slider
    UISlider *slider = sender;

    // get your view or use the ivar if you have it in one
    UIView *view = [self.view viewWithTag:12];

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, slider.value, slider.value);
    view.transform = transform;
}
```

When you create the slider you may want to start the value at 1 if your view is starting at full size.